# Motorcycle whining in first gear

Tags: motorcycle, transmission

The bike is a 2013 Kawasaki W800 with 30k km/ 18k miles on the clock. I'm the original owner and have looked after it very well - oil and filter change every 5k km/ 3.1k miles, followed the correct break-in procedure to a T and have kept up with chain and sprocket lubrication and replacement.

Recently I noticed my bike makes a whining sound when accelerating in first gear - kind of sounds like a car in reverse. The sound lessens the faster you accelerate and is more pronounced when the engine is warm. Other gears are fine. I'm guessing it's a bearing issue. I'm just a bit miffed because I looked after it so well.

Would anyone know why this happened and is it a concern (I mostly commute in peak hour with it, so a lot of slow lane filtering bouncing between 1st and 2nd).

Comment: Have you recently replaced a chain? could it be too tight/loose?

Comment: @Mauro yes, actually I did recently replace the chain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given there was a recent change to the chain, if too much tension was placed on the drive gear  (small gear near the engine)/bearing it could have caused some damage.

- Check the chain for the correct tension (on most bikes there is a sticker on the swingarm showing how much slack there should be).
- With the chain off the drive gear, check the gear for play/lateral movement

If the whining goes away with the correct tension then you have found your culprit.  If the drive gear has lateral play then there is a good chance you have a damaged bearing causing the whining.